# How to pause a loop mid-iteration

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to pause a loop mid-iteration (any point during a long series of commands in a while statement). While I understand how to use event handles to pause at the end of an iteration, I am unsure how to achieve a similar effect during the sequence of commands.

An example for clarity:

```
Thread 1 :

    while (true) 
    {
    // commands
    }

    Thread 2 : 

    Console.ReadLine();

//if 1 is pressed the first thread (Thread 1) must immediately pause.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. P.S I am a beginner so a detailed explanation would be invaluable.

Comment: explain your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am unsure how to achieve a similar effect during the sequence of commands.

Put simply: you shouldn't. Unless you have knowledge of what code is doing at any point, you shouldn't try to interrupt it. Of course, if that code **elects** to invoke the same "While I understand how to use event handles to pause at the end of an iteration" logic in the middle of a flow, then fine - but that is for **the running code** to decide, not the controlling code. Pausing arbitrary code is a great way to break things, which is why [`Thread.Suspend` has been deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx).

But *this* is perfectly valid:

```
while (true) 
{
    ElectivePauseIfNeeded();
    // ... some commands
    ElectivePauseIfNeeded();
    // ... some more commands
}
```

The point here is that it is the loop that decides when it is safe to pause, not the outside code.